# postgreSQL issue with query statement

Tags: postgresql

I am learning postgreSQL and I am having what is probably a very basic issue for most.  I have looked in to so many different ways to get this query to work but it will not work according to what I am required to complete.  Mind you, this is not a homework question but from a different resource.  The question is, What are the most popular three articles of all time? Which articles have been accessed the most? Present this information as a sorted list with the most popular article at the top.  The query statements I have tried so far are

```
news=> select articles.title, count(log.path) as art_view from log,
articles group by articles.title;
           title                | art_view
------------------------------------+----------
Bears love berries, alleges bear   |  1677735
Bad things gone, say good people   |  1677735
Balloon goons doomed               |  1677735
Trouble for troubled troublemakers |  1677735
There are a lot of bears           |  1677735
Media obsessed with bears          |  1677735
Candidate is jerk, alleges rival   |  1677735
Goats eat Google's lawn            |  1677735
(8 rows)

news=> select articles.title, count(log.path) as art_view from log, 
articles where status != '404 NOT FOUND' group by articles.title;
           title                | art_view
------------------------------------+----------
Bears love berries, alleges bear   |  1664827
Bad things gone, say good people   |  1664827
Balloon goons doomed               |  1664827
Trouble for troubled troublemakers |  1664827
There are a lot of bears           |  1664827
Media obsessed with bears          |  1664827
Candidate is jerk, alleges rival   |  1664827
Goats eat Google's lawn            |  1664827
(8 rows)

news=> select articles.title, count(log.path) as art_view from articles, 
log where status != '404 NOT FOUND' group by title;
           title                | art_view
------------------------------------+----------
Bears love berries, alleges bear   |  1664827
Bad things gone, say good people   |  1664827
Balloon goons doomed               |  1664827
Trouble for troubled troublemakers |  1664827
There are a lot of bears           |  1664827
Media obsessed with bears          |  1664827
Candidate is jerk, alleges rival   |  1664827
Goats eat Google's lawn            |  1664827
(8 rows)

news=> select articles.title, count(log.path) as art_view from articles 
join log on log.path where status !='404 NOT FOUND' group by title;
ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 1: ...t(log.path) as art_view from articles join log on log.path 
w...
                                                         ^
news=> select articles.title, count(log.path) as art_view from articles 
join log on substr(log.path) where status !='404 NOT FOUND' group by   
title;
ERROR:  function substr(text) does not exist
LINE 1: ...t(log.path) as art_view from articles join log on 
substr(log...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might 
need to add explicit type casts.
news=>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `from log,articles` CROSS JOIN between log and articles doesn't make any sense

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is create a query that returns the most popular articles by views.  I know it needs a group by at end by article title.  I also believe it needs a concatenate for the log.path but everything I have tried to use it not working.

Comment: provide structure - otherwise how we can help you?..